# Proof of O(loga n) = O(logb n), for any base a or b

Tags: algorithm, big-o, logarithm

I am revising for my exams and this question appears on a past paper:

Show that **O(loga n) = O(logb n)** for any choice of logarithmic bases a and b working from the mathematical definition of the order notation f(n) E O(g(n)).

Could someone please show me how to solve this?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule for changing base of a logarithm is: log_b(n) = log_a(n) / log_a(b).

This immediately implies log_b(n) = O(log_a(n)) and by symmetry log_a(n) = O(log_b(n)).

Answer (score 7):

Hint: `log_a(n) == ln(n) / ln(a)`.